# R - Delete string in character vector that begins with capital letter

Tags: r, regex, extract, uppercase

I have a df:

`df <- c("hello goodbye Delete Me", "Another Sentence good program", "hello world The End")`

I want this:

`c("hello goodbye", "good program", "hello world")`

I have tried:

`df <- grep("^[A-Z]", df, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`

but this deletes the entire character that starts with a capital letter:

`c("hello goodbye Delete Me", "hello world The End")`

How do I do this?

Comment: In case you need to handle Unicode and words with uppercase letters inside the word, you may [use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418335/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern, and then replace with just a single space:

```regex
\s*[A-Z]\w+\s*
```

This will capture all words beginning with capital letters, along with any whitespace which might appear on either side.  The outer call to `trimws()` is there to remove any spaces which might remain at the very start or end, as a leftover of the replacement logic.

```r
x <- c("nice to meet You however", "cat Ran away", "Cat", "Dog")
trimws(gsub('\\s*[A-Z]\\w+\\s*', ' ', x))

[1] "nice to meet however" "cat away"             ""                    
[4] ""
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use -

```
trimws(gsub('[A-Z]\\w+', '', df))
#[1] "hello goodbye" "good program"  "hello world"
```

Comment: what about for this:

```c("nice to meet You however", "cat Ran away", "Cat", "Dog")```

to this:

```c("nice to meet however", "cat away", "", "")```

so as not to leave extra spaces in between?

Comment: In that case replace more than 1 space with only 1 space - `gsub('\\s+', ' ', gsub('[A-Z]\\w+', '', df))`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df, "[^ ]+ [^ ]+")
```

Output:

```
[1] "hello goodbye"    "Another Sentence" "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following three solutions:

```r
df <- c("hello goodbye Delete Me", "Another Sentence good program", "hello world The End", "an iPhone", "Ещё Одно слово")

## Base R gsub with default TRE regex engine:
trimws(gsub("\\s*\\b[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*\\b", "", df))

## Base R gsub with PCRE regex engine:
trimws(gsub("(*UCP)\\s*\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\b", "", df, perl=TRUE))

## stringr::str_replace_all with ICU regex engine:
library(stringr)
str_trim(str_replace_all(df, "\\s*\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\b", ""))
```

Output is `[1] "hello goodbye" "good program"  "hello world"   "an iPhone"   "слово"` for all three. Please note that the word boundary is crucial to handle words like `iPhone` correctly.

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/k7EY2Z). Also, see [the PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yaygok/1) showing how the regex works (you can go [here to watch the internals of the regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/yaygok/1/debugger)).

*Regex details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[[:upper:]]` / `\p{Lu}` - any Unicode uppercase letter
- `[[:alpha:]]*` - any zero or more letters
- `\b` - a word boundary

The `(*UCP)` in the PCRE regex enables the Unicode property classes in the regex.

`trimws` is necessary to remove the leading/trailing spaces in case they appear after the replacements.